# MSAccess VBA: How to display number with preceding 0?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have the following zip codes in a linked table.
My query pulls from this linked table.

```
01234
00123
12345
12345-6789
```

Problem: The preceding zeros are truncated.
I have tried adding an apostrophe to convert to string: `="'" & [PCode]`
But that is not a nice solution.

Please help.
Thanks.

Comment: are they stored as text fields? or numeric?

Comment: Marc B, given that there is a "-" in his example, I would assume text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Postal Code: IIf([PCode] Like "####","0" & [PCode],IIf([PCode] Like "#####-",Left([PCode],Len([PCode])-1),IIf([PCode] Like "#########",Format([PCode],"@@@@@-@@@@"),[PCode])))
```

Answer (score 1):

Format should suit:

```
p="12345-6789"
?Format(p,"00000")
12345-6789

p="123"
?Format(p,"00000")
00123
```

However, if you have a number longer than 5 digits that requires preceding zeros, you will need an IIF:

```
p="123-6789"
?Format(p,"00000")
123-6789
```